# How to update version of a Flutter Web deployed in Firebase Hosting

Tags: versioning, flutter-web, firebase-hosting

In older versions of Flutter, the web/index.html file was built with a script inside that calls main.dart.js but this script was removed in newer versions and I used to add a "version" attribute to specify the version, how to update the version of my flutter web deployed on Firebase Hosting? Is there any other way to that now?

```
/// Original
<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>

/// Modified
<script src="main.dart.js?version=10" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up adding this script manually inside the body tag and disabled cache in firebase.json file.

index.html

```
<script src="main.dart.js?version=10" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build/web",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],

    "headers": [

      {
        "source": "**",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "no-cache"
          }
        ]
      }

    ]
  }


}
```

Comment: Not working still getting older version

Answer (score 4):

try running

- `flutter clean`  `flutter pub get`
- `flutter build web` then `firebase deploy`

Comment: Here I got it, but running the ´flutter clean´ command before.

Answer (score 0):

1. Adjust your project and save the changes;
2. Change the version on pubspec.yaml (from 1.0.0+1 to 1.0.1+1 for example);
3. Run flutter build web
4. Run firebase deploy

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).